# Create a bat file to copy a database from a network server to local PC C:\Users\"username" folder

Tags: batch-file

We have an Access database on a network drive that I copy to numerous local PCs. The local PCs have a shortcut on their desktop that points the the database in C:\USERS\"username".

We make numerous modifications to forms and reports on the server copy, then copy to each individual PC.

I want to create a bat/cmd that a user can run from their desktop that will automate this. If I "hard code" the user name it works fine:
User = msmith

```
copy "\\XX-DC\Company\Estimator's Data\XX_Bids.accdb" C:\Users\msmith
```

When I try the below

```
copy "\\XX-DC\Company\Estimator's Data\XX_Bids.accdb" C:\Users\%USERNAME%
```

It does not appear to copy to the C drive at all.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you already try putting a backslash after the `username` ( `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\` )?

Comment: Try using `C:\%HOMEPATH` instead of `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`. Homepath expands to the Users folder and current user so it may be an error with your environment variable `%USERNAME%`

Comment: You mean `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` :-)

Comment: Beautiful!  %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% was the answer

Comment: …or `%UserProfile%`, which is the complete user-specific path…